# Can I use urls parameter again in Django?

Tags: html, django, django-urls

```
path('list/<location_id>/', views.MyView.as_view(), name='myview'),
path('list/<location_id>/<category_id>/', views.MyView.as_view(), name='myview_category')
```

I use homepage 'myapp/list/2/', 'myapp/list/4/', ...
I want to use category function in myview.
But I can't write urls links that use location_id again in HTML.

```
<li><a href="{% url 'cafeyo:myview_category' location_id=# category_id=1 %}">category 1</a></li>
```

How can I use location_id???
Please Help me...

Comment: You must include them in the context dictionary if you want to use them in the template.

Comment: @Selcuk Thank you!! your advice is BEST!